# javascript for enabling/disabling 2 date range/date in Cognos

Tags: javascript, cognos

I am looking for javascript for enabling/disabling two date range/date
prompts in Cognos.

Does anyone have any javascript for disabling/enabling two date range prompts? If I select the Date1 prompt, then the Date2 prompt has to be greyed out and vice versa.

I am using Cognos 8.3 SP2.

Comment: @debabrata: you should avoid wording like 'can anyone send me the javascript ... '

Answer (score 0):

How about taking the approach of conditionally rendering one date prompt or another based upon a selection from a radio button or combo box?  Doing this would ensure that only one prompt is selected, and would not require javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'll admit I usually put jQuery into my Cognos reports nowadays.  If you don't have the ability to put it into a local library, you can link to the Google hosting of it.  You do this using an HTML Element with a script tag inside it (detailed explanation [here](http://blogs.utexas.edu/rdh423/2010/06/11/how-to-add-jquery-to-a-cognos-8-report/)).

Second, you can put HTML Element (div or span tags with an id) around the prompts.  This gives you a way to easily select them.

Third, you bind a function to each one (using .click() ) which uses the .hide() jQuery function on the other.